# Nested queries in mysql which return primary key?

Tags: mysql, primary-key

Q. print the complete details of the product which is ordered by the maximum number of customers and its price is greater than 3.0

products

```
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| productID    | int         | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Name         | varchar(30) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Price        | double(3,2) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| CoffeeOrigin | varchar(30) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

orders

```
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| orderID    | int      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| productID  | int      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| customerID | int      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| Date_Time  | DateTime | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

query:

```
select * from products where productID=y.id (
  select y.id from (
    select products.productsID as id, count(*) as counter 
    from orders join products on orders.productID=products.productID
    group by productID order by counter desc limit 1
  ) y
);
```

what is that I m doing is not correct?

Comment: Note that columns called price are rarely DOUBLE; it's why DECIMAL was invented

Comment: Just following the specifications provided by my instructor.

Comment: Well perhaps you can let them know

Comment: Somewhere in there, you would want a count of distinct customers (and some kind of check whether the highest count was unique, or shared with other products)

Comment: Luckily, the highest count is unique. I have verifies through other queries. The logic is clear to me but am unable frame a query.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

First, if you use a scalar subquery, you don't need to give it a table alias `y`. You only need to assign a table alias if you use a subquery as a derived table. That is, in the FROM clause.

Second, if you compare `productID` to the result of the scalar subquery, you don't need to reference the `y.ID`. The subquery expression itself can be the right hand side of the comparison.

You can write expressions to compare to a scalar subquery like this:

```
WHERE productID = ( ... subquery... )
```

No table alias following the subquery, and no need to reference `y.ID`.

Comment: I am unable to retrieve the productID of the product where the counter is maximum. It would be great if you can help with the query.!                                                                          select * from products where productID = (select products.productID, count(*) as counter from orders join products on orders.productID=products.productID group by products.productID having products.Price > 3 order by counter desc limit 1)